# Can 'make a/the/one's list' mean either "create a list" or "manage to get into the list"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Let's say ***I made your list***. Does it mean *I managed to get into your list* or *I created a list for you*? Do we have to rely on context to determine which meaning is intended?

Is there any difference among *make a list*, *make the list* and *make one's list*?

Answer (score -1):

It is difficult to say anything without having *more context.* Adding more ambiguity is the use of 'your' and not 'you' (which makes the list *personal*).

Just like *I made your clothes,* *I made your list* may work where it means that you helped someone make *his/her* list. But as I said, more context will clarify it further. If you get *into* the list, I'd add a preposition - I made *to* your list. Nevertheless, a more-common expression I've come across is to say *I managed to ...*

As far as the second part of the question is concerned, it's very clear -

> make ***a*** list - make *any/random* list 
>  make ***the*** list - very specific (the listener and the speaker both know which list they are talking about) and, 
>  make ***one's*** list - generalized, can refer to *any* person's list.

Comment: Well, *make the list* is probably an idiom as in "The Eiffel Tower would have made their list".

Comment: Native English speakers wouldn't say *I made to your list*; *made* needs an object, and *to* is the wrong preposition.  They might say *I got onto your list; I made it onto your list*; or maybe even *I made your list.*